# Ruby Selenium - find_elements if nil => Net::ReadTimeout

Tags: ruby, selenium, find, element

Hi I got `Net::ReadTimeout` every time I use `find_elements` when there are no elements like this. A short example my Feature-file: (cucamber)

```
Feature: Retest Faild Testcases
Scenario: Simpel test find_elements
    Given open website humblebundle.com
    And search for civilization
```

my ruby step-file:

```
Given /^open website (.*)$/ do |url|
  $driver.navigate.to "http://www."+url
  $wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 180)
  $wait.until {
    $driver.find_element(:css => "div[class='navbar-content']").displayed?
  }
end

And /^search for (.*)$/ do |name|
  element=$driver.find_element(:css => "input[placeholder='Search']")
  element.send_keys name
  sleep(1)
  element.send_keys :enter
  sleep(10)
#line199  items=$driver.find_elements(:id => "Games")
  puts items.count
end
```

and the error I get:

> Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout
>   ./features/step_definitions/basic_steps.rb:199:in `/^search for (.*)$/'
>   ./features/a_test.feature:4:in`And search for civilization'

I would be very thankful for any help with this.

Comment: It looks like you are using an implicit wait. When the implicit wait is greater than 0, the driver waits for at least one element with `find_elements` before returning a response to the client. So you'll get a connection timeout when it doesn't find any element.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the timeout for a request is set to `60` seconds. If your implicit wait setting is set to greater than this value, you will get a `Net::ReadTimeout` if no elements are located. You must keep your implicit wait setting less than your request timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was it. 
I change the implicit wait 2 secends lesser than my ReadTimeout.